# different between init vs get only property?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

What are the differences between init vs get only property in C#?

Sample:

```
public class person
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public string Family { get; }
    }
```

I tried to figure it out, I understand both of them to make your property readonly but I couldn't figure out what is the difference and when we should choose one of them against another one.

Comment: One will make a readonly property **from the outside** while the other will make a truly readonly property. That's basically the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Get only properties can only be set during initialisation of the object. Private set will allow you to change the property from within that class at any time.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is you are allowed to set the `Name` from within the class. Whereas `Family` is readonly so it can only be set from the constructor.

For example

```cs
var p = new Person("fam");
p.SetName("name");

public class Person
{
    public Person(string family) // constructor
    {
        Family = family;
    }
        
    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        Name = name; // allowed from within
    }
        
    public void SetFamily(string family)
    {
        Family = family; // error
    }
    
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Family { get; }
}
```